# Helper tool to refactor large python file into smaller files

Tags: python, refactoring

I have a 3000+ line python file (call it `orig`) containing 30ish utility functions. I'd like to split it into 5 files (say `A.py`, `B.py`, etc).

After the split, is there a helper tool to change all the `orig.func1` and `orig.func2` in the entire repo to `A.func1`, `B.func2`?

Comment: Is a script necessary? You might be able to get away with just using a text editor's find all + replace functionality.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, yes, but I'd have to do it 30 times...

Comment: I suppose you could read in the source code line by line and do `.replace()`? You'd still have to type in all of the things you want to replace though.

Answer (score 0):

As @BrokenBenchmark suggested, I ended up writing my own helper in python

```
lines = open('calc.py').readlines()

out = []
for line in lines:
    if 'orig.' in line:
        m = re.search('orig.(.*?)\(', line)
        f = m.group(1)    
        if f in dir(A):
            line = line.replace('orig.', 'A.')
        elif f in dir(B):
            line = line.replace('orig.', 'B.')

        # and other modules

        else:
            raise ValueError
    out.append(line)
            
open('calc2.py', 'w').writelines(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that [Rope](https://github.com/python-rope/rope) can help you with.

You need to do a MoveGlobal Refactoring. If [your IDE/editor has Rope support](https://github.com/python-rope/rope/wiki/How-to-use-Rope-in-my-IDE-or-Text-editor%3F) and it supports move refactoring, it would probably support MoveGlobal as well.